# Navigate to different route with value get from DataStore

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I got my app with Term and Agreement Screen load first time. I will save a flag to androidx Datastore that user already agree with Term list.

But where I try to get that value from DataStore to determine which route I will navigate to. It seem ignored my updated value from DataStore.

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(...) {

  val isAccepted = remember {
    dataStore.getIsTermAgreementAccepted
  }.collectAsState(initial = false)

  val splashScreenRedirect = Destinations.TERM_AGREEMENT_ROUTE

  if (isAccepted.value == true) {
    splashScreenRedirect = Destinations.DEVICE_ROUTE
  }

  composable(Destinations.SPLASH_ROUTE) {
      SplashScreen(
        modifier,
        delayTime = 1000L
      ) {
        navController.navigate(splashScreenRedirect)
      }
    }
}
```

But app always go to Destinations.TERM_AGREEMENT_ROUTE.

Comment: where are you setting `isAccepted` to `true`?

Comment: @404NotFound value of `getIsTermAgreementAccepted` in `dataStore` is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for your behaviour lies within this snippet:

```
.collectAsState(initial = false)
```

The first value that this `Flow` emits is `false`. When the `DataStore` then is accessed and the actual value is read from there, the `Flow` emits the value `true`. But at that point in time, it's already too late, as the `navController` already navigated away. 
Once the actual value is emitted, the destination does not update, as you do not `remember` the `splashScreenRedirect` variable. If you wrapped this variable into a `remember`, I **think** the destination would refresh.

```
var splashScreenRedirect by remember { mutableStateOf(Destinations.TERM_AGREEMENT_ROUTE) }
```

You still would get a nasty flash of the wrong destination though, so it might be better to implement a logic that ignores the default value. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73601607/8331157) for reference.

A boolean representing whether the terms were accepted probably is not enough, you would need a data structure that can hold the three states like `UNKNOWN`, `LICENSE_ACCEPTED`, `LICENSE_NOT_ACCEPTED`. Then use UNKNOWN as the `Flow` initial value, and only do the navigation if `splashScreenRedirect != UNKOWN`.